# Using json to store remote database locally

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to cache data from remote database locally to use it in my javascript application. I do not need any excesses such as SQL requests to local data, so I decide just to store database records in array of objects in the following way:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 var json0 = '{"1" : {"fname": "fname1", "sname": "sname1"}, "2" : {"fname": "fname2", "sname": "sname2"}}';
 var json1 = '{"2" : {"data": "11/05/2014", "time": "11:30:18", "person": "data0[1]"}, "6" : {"data": "24/06/2014", "time": "16:11:05", "person": "data0[2]"}, "8" : {"data": "11/10/2014", "time": "12:15:27", "person": "data0[1]"}}';
 var data0 = JSON.parse(json0);
 var data1 = JSON.parse(json1, function (k, v) {
    try {
      return  eval(v); 
    } catch (e) {
        return v;
    }         
});
 console.log(data1);
</script>
```

The question is about the memory usage. If the objects in array **data1** will store the reference to the objects from **data0** in the property "*person*" or they will store the copy of these objects?

Comment: Have a look at localStorage (which is available to most modern browsers) : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as reducing version of your example shows, data0 will be stored by reference.

```
var tt = {f1: 'aa', f2: 'bb'}
var rr = eval('tt');

console.log(rr.f1); // 'aa'
rr.f1 = 'cc';
console.log(tt.f1); // 'cc'
```

But using `eval(..)` is bad way: [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) . Use local storage instead as jeff said.